# Pass the login details to another page using session PHP

Tags: php, session, authentication

I need the  login details in another page for retrieving the data from the database. Basically, I need to display the editable form with the details of the user logged in. I tried `session_register()` for storing the username in login.php page. But for some reason I am not able to display the username using `$_SESSION[]` in my edit.php page. I am doing this after the function `session_start()` as well.

I am new to php, so don't know whether I misunderstood session! Or is there any other way to pass the login details?

Thanks in advance

My code:

```
**Login.php**
      <?php
       $userName = $_POST['username'];
      $password = $_POST['password'];
      //Connect to the database
      //query the database
        if($rows==1)
       {
      session_start();
       $_SESSION['user']=$userName;
     header("location:edit_user.php");
     }
      else
      {
     echo 'Data Does Not Match <br /> Re-Enter UserName and Password';
     }
     ?>

**In edit.php**
    <?php
    session_start();
    if(!isset($_SESSION['user']))
   {
    header("location:login_form.php");
   }
   else
   {
    echo $_SESSION['user'];
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: Can you show us the session related code from both pages (should be the first few lines of each file...)?

Comment: @jeroen I have added my code now!

Comment: The above code works!I made a syntax error..I added session_start() in all the pages. I removed the session_register() and used $_SESSION to store content needed throughout the session. Thanks for helping me to understand!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all make sure that you place `session_start()` at the very beginning of any script you use it in. There can be no output to the browser before you call `session_start()` and that includes spaces or new-lines before the opening `<?php` tag.

So:

```
<?php
session_start();
...
```

Second, make sure you terminate your script after a redirect, for example:

```
header("location:edit_user.php");
exit();
```

That makes sure that no code after the redirect gets executed, so sessions won't get unset or session variables changed by accident.

Answer (score 1):

`session_register()` is a deprecated function. Just use `$_SESSION["bar"] = "foo"` to store something.

Answer (score 1):

for future references, please post parts of your code when you are asking questions. It helps everyone to give you an answer in more specific cases.

```
<?php
session_start();

if(!isset($_SESSION['Foo']))
{
    $_SESSION['Foo'] = "Bar";
}
?>
```

---

Source : http://php.net/manual/en/features.sessions.php

Answer (score 0):

you can retrive data from the database like this

```
//start connection
$connect = mysql_connect(DB_SERVER,DB_USER,DB_PASSWORD);
if(!$connect){
    die("Database connection Error".mysql_error());
}

//select database
$db = mysql_select_db(DB_NAME);
if(!$db){
    die("Database selection Error".mysql_error());
}

//get data
$login = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM TABLENAME where user_id={$_SESSION['user_id']}");
$login_data = mysql_fetch_array($login);
```

now $login_data array has the user details which you can point to form text field values..

the $_session['user_id']=$login_data['user_id'] value has to be assigned earlier which stays in the $_SESSION global variable through out the session

Comment: I need to store $_SESSION['xyz']=$userName where $userName=$_POST['username']. Am I wrong with the syntax?

Comment: You can directly assign $_SESSION['xyz']=$_POST['username'] but for that you need the username data field from a form. You can take that data while user is logging in after verifying his login.